# Postgres Slow and delayed insertions

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, postgresql

I have and issue with database inserting slowly and delayed manner. 
What the situation is, I have a table `mobiledata` which has a high insertion in it. It has a primary key as id (bigserial). The id nextval is from sequence mobiledata_seq. 
When I see the insertions in table, the row is inserted while missing the sequence. Also the row is inserted after some time say 10 sec
This happens in rare cases and sometimes it works like a charm.

Example:

```
Select id from missingdata order by id desc limit 100;
```

```
output
611815
611813
611810
611809
611807
611805
611804
611802
611801
611800
611799
611798
611797
611796
611795
```

Comment: Sounds more like some transactions are discarding calls from `nextval`. Gaps in a sequence generated column do **not** mean something is missing. Also sequence _caching_ could play a role here.

Comment: First: check the postgres logfile (and maybe the application logfile, if any)

Answer (score 0):

If your insertion rate is very high, it is possible that server is struggling to flush your data to disk. Another possibility is if you created too many indexes on this table, server has to update all of them during insert, and that can become very expensive.

Solutions for this could be:

- run pgtune utility on your postgresql.conf to be sure that your server config is reasonable
- drop some unnecessary indexes on this table
- improve disk subsystem, e.g. install SSD
- add memory

As for missing ids - it will happen if some of the insert transactions are rolled back for any reason, including clients abruptly closing connections.

Whether this is normal or not it is hard to say - depends on your workflow. But you should not try to reclaim missing ids - in transactional database it is simply not worth it.

Comment: Flushing data to disk has nothing to do with "seeing" the data from SQL.

Comment: If his insert rate is higher than disk streaming speed, server will be thrashing and will have hard time responding to most queries

Comment: It might take some time for the insert (or the commit) to succeed. But _if_ the commit went through, the results _will_ be visible to others even if the data hasn't been physically written to the disk

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: if the commit went through, data IS physically written to disk. If this is not the case, it cannot be called commit (unless you play dangerous and set fsync=off)